# XSLT Length condition

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to check the 'Title' for not empty before starting any processing.

example below tag is considered empty, when the child tag is from one from the Ignored List.
Ignored List contains around 10-15 tags.

```
<Title>
  <Comment>Comment code</Comment>
</Title>
```

Sample Code :

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="Title and normalize-space(Title) != ''">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Title" mode="xyz"/>                    
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-templates name="getalternative_label" mode="xyz"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: What's the ignored list? A string? A node set?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Ignored List is list of nodes and the problem is to check for  Title Empty.Need to Modify Line  " <xsl:when test="Title and normalize-space(Title) != ''"> " , to return string without the text of Ignored child nodes. example 1 will return empty title                                           <Title>
  <Comment>Comment code</Comment>
</Title> example 2 will return'Title text' <Title>
  <b><i>Title text</i></b>
</Title>

Answer (score 0):

This XPath would probably do the job

```
Title[text()[normalize-space() != '']]
```

Comment: This is wrong. For once, you'd need `normalize-space(.)`. Also, it fails for the actual example provided by the author, where the non-empty text node (after `normalize-space`) is below another element. Better do `../text()` instead.

Comment: You don't need the `.`, `normalize-space()` [will default to the context node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space). My understanding of the question is that `<xsl:when>` should be chosen if `<Title>` contains actual text that is not within another element. `<Comment>` is obviously not the title, it's just a comment and should not be processed as if it was the title text. This means, the given XML example will *not* be matched by the expression, but something like `<Title>title text</Title>` or `<Title>title text<Comment>Comment code</Comment></Title>` will be.

Comment: You're right about `normalize-space`. I guess the question author should clarify on how to interprete "empty" and "comment", as this definitely is a non-empty content. Now I see what the "ignore list" _might_ be.